# Finding and sorting files by size in Unix

Tags: unix, search, directory, size

I want to create a function in shell programming that gets 2 parameters, directory-name and file-name and that does the following: it searches starting in the given directory-name for the file-name and then goes in all subdirectories of the directory-name to continue the search. I want the output to be every parent-directory where the file-name has been found, sorted using the file-name size.

Help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about which Unix you asked for, but for Linux and maybe common Unix systems:

```
find <directory> -name "<filename>" -ls | sort -k 7 -n -r | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs -n 1 dirname
```

- sort => sort by file size (the 7th column of find output is filesize)
- awk => print the filename full path
- dirname => get parent directory of the matched file

Example:

```
# Find parent directory of all types.h under /usr/include, sorted by file size in desc order

$ find /usr/include/ -name "types.h" -ls | sort -k 7 -n -r | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs -n 1 dirname
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys
/usr/include/c++/7/parallel
/usr/include/rpc
/usr/include/linux/sched
/usr/include/linux/iio
/usr/include/linux
/usr/include/asm-generic
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm
```

Comment: I adjusted it a little bit, but can't get the sorting right, this is what my code looks like: find <directory> -type f -name <filename> | sort -k 7 -n -r | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}'. It doesn't get quite the sorting right, I would like the sorting to be made using the size of the $NF element and then print the corresponding $(NF-1). Maybe you can help me.

Comment: what do you want to sort? NF-1 is the date part of the timestamp

Comment: find /usr/include/ -name "types.h" -ls | awk '{print $(NF-1) " " $NF}' | sort -k 1  # use sort -k to specify column